# .net and matlab integration

Tags: .net, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am just curious. What is the cheapest and most contemporary option to integrate matlab and .net. I believe there are other options than this:

[matlab netbuilder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/netbuilder/)

Comment: do you want to use MATLAB from .NET, or do you want to use .NET from inside MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calling .NET from MATLAB, you can import .NET assemblies directly into MATLAB (either at the command line or within a program) using the command `NET.addAssembly`. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb5k6.html) for details.

If you want to call a live, installed copy of MATLAB from .NET, you can instantiate MATLAB via its COM interface and execute code. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brd0v3w.html) for details.

If you want to compile MATLAB code to a standalone .NET assembly that can be called from .NET without requiring a live installed copy of MATLAB, you would need [MATLAB Builder for .NET](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/).

Comment: Thanks. does the second option (call installed copy of matlab) require a specific toolbox?

Comment: You can call live MATLAB via its COM interface from .NET with just base MATLAB. Obviously, if you want to execute functions from toolboxes, you would need those toolboxes.

Comment: Is it also possible to compile to C++ and then call into the C++ dlls from .net? I had huge issues with the .net implementation.. the latest being that .net 4.5 is not supported. I suppose I could go around that by compiling to C++ and then calling C++ dlls?